# What's the different between the action in web api controller and the action in a general controller

Tags: .net

I searched some information about the web api.
That's an easy way to post the data to the client side such as mobile and browser.
And I have read the [article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api).

I found that if I just wrote a controller like this:

```
public HomeController:Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public void UserInfos()
    {
        UserInfo[] users = new UserInfo[]{ new UserInfo{FirstName="Tim",LastName="Lee"},  new UserInfo{FirstName="Tim2",LastName="Lee2"}} };

        return Json(users);
    }
}
```

And I can also get the json data by typing a url like this:

```
[http://]localhost:port/Home/UserInfos
```

Beside this, what the other differences between those?

Comment: Your code is not compiled, this is also not ApiController?

Comment: Yes, not api controller, just a normal controller in .net mvc 3